# serialize_precision effecting session number with NO write commands

Tags: php

A few months ago I caught PHP converting `2.59` to `2.5900000000000003` while serializing an array. The answer that fix that was the following:

```
ini_set('serialize_precision',2);//Forces 2.59 to NOT be serialized as 2.5900000000000003.
```

Unfortunately a client discovered that one of the monetary amounts was off by three cents. While it's not a big deal it does add up over time and I ultimately found out that the numeric monetary value (in this case, `2.97` was being rounded up to `3`. When I commented out the `serialize_precision` fix the `2.97` session variable *stayed* `2.97`. It makes no sense that `serialize_precision` would change anything if that variable had *absolutely no write related commands*.

So how do I:

- Force PHP to round to X.YZ and not a.bcdefg.
- Force PHP to not mess with any variables (session or otherwise) while accomplishing the first goal?

The PHP serialization of the array where the initial problem was occuring:

```
$order = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,serialize($order));
$_SESSION['minding_my_own_business']
```

Comment: The answer is not to fudge with precision settings, the answer is "Never _ever_ use floats to represent money. _**EVER**_." and you're looking at the exact reason why. http://moneyphp.org/

Answer (score 1):

So building on my comment of basically "oh god no, this is an awful idea in several different ways. *Do not do this, especially if you're dealing with actual money*."

Your assumption about `serialize_precision` is wrong. It is not "the number of digits after the decimal point", it is simply "the number of digits".

```
ini_set('serialize_precision',2);
var_dump(
    serialize(2.97)
);

ini_set('serialize_precision',3);
var_dump(
    serialize(2.97)
);
```

Output:

```
string(4) "d:3;"
string(7) "d:2.97;"
```

Whatever data has flowed through this bad code was rendered *substantially* more inaccurate than usual.

Comment: ...that demonstrates the problem, it doesn't suggest a solution. Granted you posted something in a comment and I'm working to review it. Perhaps you could please update your question to reflect usage of what you proposed in the comment?

Comment: The answer solves your stated, immediate problem: you need to set the precision to at least `3`, not `2`. The unstated problem is that you likely need to completely overhaul your application to fundamentally change the way you handle currency, which is beyond the scope of a StackOverflow question and more in the realm of "hiring a consultant".

Comment: I added a session variable to the question. The `$_SESSION` variable is being changed by the mere presence of `serialize_precision` even though I'm not making **ANY** write command to that `$_SESSION` variable. So using `serialize_precision` is not an option since it's just randomly changing variables that are completely unrelated hence why this does not answer my problem. It *does clarify* very well how the number works at least.

Answer (score 0):

Ensuring that `precision` and `serialize_precision` have the same values goes a long way to avoid floating point issues, when they are necessary.

In code you can use
`ini_set('serialize_precision', ini_get('precision'));`

or otherwise use php.ini

```
precision = 14
serialize_precision = 14
```

Both fields are defined as ["The number of significant digits displayed in floating point numbers."](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision) So you may want increase this from the example if you expect to handle large numbers.